Using Bearer token to send text messages using Twilio
I understand that we can use AccountSid and AuthToken to send text messages, or API Key and API Secret. But is it possible to send text messages using JWT Token?

No, the Twilio API is designed to be used with API keys or auth tokens only. However, you can build you own serverless function that mimics the Messaging API and protect that one with a bearer token.
